# How not to print deprecation warnings on the apache error log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, logging, deprecated

I am getting undesirable deprecation warnings on my Apache's error log:

```
/srv/www/<application>/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_view/paths.rb:15: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
```

I would like not to print these deprecation warnings when in production.

I have tried to add this to my `enviromenents/production.rb` file:

```
  config.active_support.deprecation = nil
```

and

```
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

and

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

and

```
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

Though, I had no success with any of these options, since the Apache log continue's to get my deprecation warnings.

Does anyone know how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular warning is printed by Ruby itself, it has nothing to do with `active_support`. The only way I see is to disable all `stderr`  output, but I doubt it's what you want.

**Added:**

To catch it this should help:

```
class Object
  def id
    raise
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if there is any way for me to get the stack trace of the deprecated invokation?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. What is outputting the deprecation warnings? If it's a gem outside rails (not active-something or action-something), it is probably just printing it to STDERR, which will cause it to be printed to the error log.

My suggestion would be to fix whatever is using the deprecated methods, seeing as there is probably a reason it's been deprecated.

Comment: By now, I still do not want to fix the cause of that deprecation warning. As you may see in my last edit, the object belongs in action_view.